# Retrieving Comments For facebook statuses

Tags: iphone, ios, facebook-graph-api

I am sending the following request for getting the user statuses.

```
[facebook requestWithGraphPath:@"me/statuses" andParams:params andDelegate:self];
```

Then I am storing the response received in an array.

```
 NSArray *resultData = [[result objectForKey:@"statuses"] objectForKey:@"data"];
if([resultData count] > 0) {
         for (NSUInteger i=0; i<[resultData count] && i < 25; i++) {
             [status addObject:[resultData objectAtIndex:i]];
         }
     }
```

I am able to display the statuses in a tableview.

```
cell.textLabel.text = [[status objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"message"];
```

**How can i get the comments for each status?**

Comment: LOgin u in u r id then check it https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, You should get your post id,Then hit the post id to see the comments like two steps

- https://graph.facebook.com/me/posts

Save all the post then on each post your request to fetch comments on post like this..

- https://graph.facebook.com/1558423549_3394202704692

You can get help from [here](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=me/posts)

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
https://graph.facebook.com/comments/?ids=ur_status_id_here
```

For ex: https://graph.facebook.com/comments/?ids=268172318814_10150648188293815